# gettiing OrderModule is not an ngModule error during aot-compilation

Tags: angular, angular2-aot

I have used angular-cli for scaffolding.I have app module which is bieng loaded by default, while other modules are lazily loaded.

while running:

```
ng build -prod --aot 
14% building modules 36/37 modules 1 active ...de_modules/css-loader/lib/css-base.js**OrderModule** is not an NgModule
```

Comment: What are we supposed to do with this?  There's  no code and no question.

Comment: @JohnBaird , my first question is Lazy loading supported in aot compilation? If yes, i am getting this error while aot compile, anyone has encountered it   before?

Comment: Encountering the same, after updating all packages to the newest version.. "Appmodule is not an ngModule".. Did you found the solution to this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.It is supported in latest version of angular-cli.
update your cli to latest version.

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean 
npm install -g angular-cli@latest
```